# Integral involving Bessel function

Tags: sympy

Is there any way to get sympy to perform this integral?

```
x=var('x')
L=var('L')
Q.positive(1/L)
integrate(besseli(1,x) * exp(-x**2/(4*L)-L),(x,0,inf))
```

Sympy just returns the integral:

```
Integral(exp(-L - x**2/(4*L))*besseli(1, x), (x, 0, +inf))
```

Mathematica does it:

```
Integrate[BesselI[1, x] Exp[-(x^2/(4 L)) - L], {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

Result:

```
ConditionalExpression[1 - E^-L, Re[1/L] > 0]
```

EDIT: using the answer provided below, a better way to perform this integral is:

```
L=var('L',real=True,positive=True)
x=var('x',real=True,positive=True)
integrate(besseli(1,x) * exp(-x**2/(4*L)-L),(x,0,oo))
```

Comment: Sympy gives me the right thing. What version are you running?

Comment: ```$ python -c "import sympy; print sympy.__version__"
0.7.2```  What version are *you* using?  Maybe I need the latest dev version?

Comment: Infinity in SymPy is `oo`, not `inf`.

Comment: This works for me in 0.7.2 (after changing `inf` to `oo`).

Comment: 0.7.2-git (and I changed inf to oo as asmeurer mentioned)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `inf`, which I guess is `Float('inf')`.  You want `oo`, the symbolic infinity.  SymPy should probably be smarter about converting `Float('inf')` to `oo`.

```
In [1]: x=var('x')

In [2]: L=var('L')

In [3]: Q.positive(1/L)
Out[3]: Q.positive(1/L)

In [5]: integrate(besseli(1,x) * exp(-x**2/(4*L)-L),(x,0,oo))
Out[5]:
⎧        ⎛ L    ⎞  -L              │                 ⎛      1         ⎞│   π
⎪        ⎝ℯ  - 1⎠⋅ℯ            for │periodic_argument⎜─────────────, ∞⎟│ < ─
⎪                                  │                 ⎝polar_lift(L)   ⎠│   2
⎪
⎪∞
⎪⌠
⎨⎮         2
⎪⎮        x
⎪⎮  -L - ───
⎪⎮       4⋅L
⎪⎮ ℯ        ⋅besseli(1, x) dx                    otherwise
⎪⌡
⎩0
```

Comment: I opened https://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=3866 for the `inf` vs. `oo` thing.

Comment: Thanks!  How do you generate the pretty-print output?

Comment: `pprint`, or do it automatically with `init_printing`. I am using `isympy`, which does that automatically.

Comment: The periodic_argument polar_lift stuff is probably equivalent to `re(1/L) > 0`. You can read the docstrings of those respective functions to see what they mean.  Unfortunately, SymPy right now is very bad at simplifying the conditionals that come out of integrate, so you sometimes have to do it by hand.

Comment: @parvinkarimi are you looking for a symbolic solution using SymPy? I don't know R.

Answer (score 0):

The original expression now works in SymPy because inf is automatically recast to oo:

```
>>> inf=float('inf')
>>> x=var('x')
>>> L=var('L')
>>> Q.positive(1/L)
Q.positive(1/L)
>>> integrate(besseli(1,x) * exp(-x**2/(4*L)-L),(x,0,inf))
Piecewise(
((exp(L) - 1)*exp(-L), Abs(arg(L)) < pi/2),
(Integral(exp(-L - x**2/(4*L))*besseli(1, x), (x, 0, oo)), True))
```